# How do you take inputs from a web page and store it into SQL Server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, html

I just ant to know the simplest way to do this:

A user inputs data on the fields on a web page and hits "submit". The data will be stored in a local database.

```
<div class="article">
    <form>
        <br/>
        <p>Name:</p><input type="text" id="fname"><br/>
        <p>Address:</p><input type="text" id="address"><br/>
        <p>Phone:</p><input type="text" id="phone"><br/>
        <button onclick="InsertData()">Submit</button><br/>
    </form>

<script>
    function InsertData(){
        var name=document.GetElementById('fname');
        var address=document.GetElementById('address');
        var phone=document.GetElementById('phone');
        var connectionstring="Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;UserID=sa;Password=password;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
        var statement="insert into Northwnind.dbo.directory_tab(telephoneno, name, address) values(?,?,?)";

        Database db=database.OpenConnectionString(connectionstring);
        db.Execute(statement);
        db.Close;       
    }

</script>
</div>
```

If you must know, I'm new with web programming. I really have no clue on what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way is to send a request using JavaScript which should be handled on the server you are running the web site from. For the request handler you can use perl, php or other languages. The server script is responsible for managing the database. For perl you can use the CGI module. For the JavaScript request use jQuery's AJAX.